# Notification that doesn't close the drawer when it's clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications

In android, when the user clicks (or touches) a notification, it automatically
closes the notification drawer. **Is there a way to prevent that for notifications
created by my application?**

It could be a flag set when creating the notification, or perhaps a method I can
call in the activity that's created by the notification, or even some
undocumented work around.

I just need to keep the drawer open after a notification from my app is clicked.
Anything will do.

Comment: Why is this in the user's interest?

Comment: @CommonsWare The application relies on creating a number of notifications and letting
the user click several in a row. It's not a standard use of
notifications, but it's momentary and has a few advantages. However, if the drawer closes after every click, it makes things very annoying for the user.

Comment: "The application relies on creating a number of notifications and letting the user click several in a row" -- one would imagine that there is a better UI approach for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I need a list of items which can be swiped or clicked, and which can be shown on top of the lock screen. Naturally I thought of the notification system, as it matched these requirements exactly (except for the close on click thing) and is almost trivial to implement. There certainly are alternatives, but they would simply involve manually implementing most of what's offered by the notification system, so I thought I'd look into the easier option before going deeper into alternatives. @commonsware

Comment: Since the notification drawer cannot be accessed on top of the lock screen, your solution seems flawed.

Comment: It can be accessed on top of the drag-to-unlock screen. It cannot be used on top of the pattern or pin screens (unless I rely on root access or device administration), but any manual implementation I use will have the same problem.

Comment: not only you're chasing a tough problem, but making it tough on user to see other app's notifications if you flood the drawer with your own.  My advice: show just one notification Item in the drawer, let it summarize the bunch of notifications your app intends to show. When user touches it, show an activity with your huge list of notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Using PendingIntent.getBroadcast to set up your intents does this...

i was actually looking for a way to make it close using that method when i found your post...

Edit:
i should probably note that my notification is ongoing, i have not tested this on a normal "dismissable" intent...

i have tested the PendingIntent.getActivity and PendingIntent.getService methods and found that they both cause the drawer to close on click....

**the work around that i am using is to use getActivity to start an activity...  that activity sends the needed intents to other classes or apps as the case may be...**